# Babel command line not transpiling import statements - React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have the following JSX file.

```
import React from "react";

export default class Code extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div></div>
    }
}

React.render(<Code />, document.getElementById('code'));
```

I'm running Babel from the command line using the following

```
babel --plugins transform-react-jsx app.jsx -d dist
```

I get the following output

```
import React from "react";
export default class Code extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement("div", null);
  }

}
React.render(React.createElement(Code, null), document.getElementById('code'));
```

This obviously does not run in the browser since import and export are not valid. What settings do I need to specify for Babel to transfrom es6 imports?

Here is my .babelrc file

```
{
    "plugins": [
        [
            "transform-react-jsx",
            {
                "pragma": "dom" // default pragma is React.createElement
            },
        ]
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `preset-react` instead which will also include `transform-react-jsx` plugin.

1. Install the preset module `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react`
2. Add the presets to your `.babelrc` file, i.e.

   {
     "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
   }
3. Run your babel script `babel app.jsx -d dist`

If you don't want to add `.babelrc` file just run the script as so after installing the preset module `babel --presets @babel/preset-react app.jsx -d dist`

More information on the `preset-react` [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react)

Comment: Thanks Van, I tried that. Still get the same output. Imports and Classes intact. I tried adding @babel/preset-env and that helped convert the classes and the imports too. But when I run the app in the browser, I get an error in the console saying "require is not defined"

Comment: @Arun hmm ic, let me try it

Comment: @Arun may I know which browser that you're using to run the app? Adding `@babel/preset-env` will transpile the code (i.e. `import` to `require`) for node but not for browser. Suggest to use bundler like `webpack` to bundle your source into resources accesible from browser. Perhaps creating the react app using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) will be easier and save a lot of time trying to configure the webpack configs.